# Laravel update unique column

Tags: php, laravel

I have update function below but it returns this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name1' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `groups` where `name1` = postman group)
```

> **issue:** ID added to column name:  `Unknown column 'name1'`, I can't see where this happens.

## Code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = $request->user();
    $group = Group::findOrFail($id);
    $isAdmin = $user->groupsAdmin()->whereName($group->name)->exists();
    if($isAdmin) {
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:groups,name' . $id,
            'description' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
        ];
        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $rules['photo'] = 'mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png|max:2048';
        }
        $this->validate($request, $rules);

        $group->name = $request->input('name');
        $group->description = $request->input('description');
        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $photo = $request->file('photo');
            $filename = 'Group' . '-' . time() . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('images');
            $request->file('photo')->move($location, $filename);

            $oldFilename = $group->photo;
            $group->photo = $filename;
            if(!empty($group->photo)){
                Storage::delete($oldFilename);
            }
        }
        $group->save();
        return response()->json([
            'data' => new GroupResource($group),
            'message' => 'Your group updated successfully.'
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => null,
            'message' => 'Only admins can edit group details.'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: use a `dd()` to debug..

Comment: I think it's just a little typo error, check your postman column name. As your error says "where `name1` = postman group" you typed name1 instead of name

Comment: @AliAli nah in postman all is good :/

Comment: @hacker315 `{
    "name": "required|string|max:255|unique:groups,name1",
    "description": "nullable|string|max:255"
}`

Comment: which line exactly causes the problem? is it mentioned in the exception?

Comment: @UzairRiaz the error comes from `$rules` (my comment above)

Comment: does name1 exist in your table? `'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:groups,name' . $id,` tells it to look for name in `groups` table, column `'name'.$id` which becomes name1

Comment: @UzairRiaz no! column name is `name` that `1` is group id we pass it to rules in order to not return error if during update user didn't want to change name. `name` column is unique that's why will return error during update and we need pass model id

Comment: yeah you need put a comma after name to do this `'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:groups,name,' . $id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a comma after the `groups,name` since the unique rule is written like so `unique:table,column,except,idColumn`

From laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique